# DataWindows not loaded with executable version

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow, powerbuilder-build-deploy

We are working with the Power Builder 2019 R3 build 2703.
Our software works with an Oracle 11.2.04 database.
Our Windows version is 21H1 build 19043.1288.

Since a few days, the compiled version of our application does not work properly on some of our Dell laptops. The DataWindows no longer load.

Have you already experienced this problem?
What components do you need to distribute with our executable so that everything works properly?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So it works on some systems and not others?  Do you get any error messages?  When you say 'do not load' do you mean the data is not retrieved from the database or something else?  Have you traced the database to see if the calls (SQL Statements) are being sent?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
In fact the application is running on about 100 machines. For the past two weeks, we have had three machines on which the DataWindows no longer display but the SQL queries in the code continue to work. 
I'm going to set up a messagebox to determine if the DataWindows retrieval returns an error or not.

Comment: Two things come to mind.
The connection to the database failed or 
the PBD with your datawindows cannot be read.

I would TNSPING from the failing machines. Also test to see if sqlplus will connect

Comment: Hello,
The connection to the database works because some screens work such as the authentication screen. My datawindow is unreadable, its container is empty. 
Thank you for your help

Comment: Did the dataobject get deployed?  If the entire dataobject is blank then maybe not.  Is it a new dataobject that didn't get checked in, or maybe something missing from PBR file, or didn't choose PBD build option?  Just a few guesses.